# Smart Table data is disappearing when sorting

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have created a custom directive with Typescript angular for smart table. But when I sort the columns table data is disappearing... When I write the same only with angular js. It works fine.

Can you please help what I did wrong...

**Grid-HTML**

```
<table st-safe-src="rowCollection" st-table="gridOptions" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort="type">Type</th>
            <th  st-sort="name">Name</th>
            <th  st-sort="address">Address</th>
            <th ng-if="city">City/State</th>
            <th ng-if="zip">Zip</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in options">
            <td width="20%">{{row.type | uppercase}}</td>
            <td width="20%">{{row.name  | uppercase}}</td>
            <td width="30%">{{row.address | uppercase}}</td>
            <td width="15%" ng-if="city">{{row.cityState | uppercase}}</td>
            <td width="15%" ng-if="zip">{{row.zip | uppercase}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Typescript controller**

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/app.d.ts" />

namespace app.widgets {
    'use strict';


interface IGridAttributes extends ng.IAttributes {
     cityVisible: string;   
     zipVisible: string;    
     options: string;    
 } 

export class updGridCtrl {

    static $inject: Array<string> = ['$scope', '$filter'];
    constructor(private scope: ng.IFormController) {
        this.activate();
    }

    gridOptions: any = null;
    city: boolean;
    zip: boolean;

    activate() {}
}

class LtcgUpdGridDirective implements ng.IDirective {

    static instance(): ng.IDirective { return new LtcgUpdGridDirective(); }
    restrict: string = 'E';        
    transclude = true;
     scope = {
        'cityVisible': "@",
        'zipVisble': "@",
        'options': '='
    }; 

    templateUrl = 'views/widgets/ltcg-updgrid.html';       

    link = (scope: any, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: IGridAttributes, ctrl: any) => {   
        scope.gridOptions = scope.options //private scoped from options : '=',  

        scope.city = true;
        scope.zip = true;
        console.log(scope.zipVisible);

            if (attrs.cityVisible == "no") {
                scope.city = false;                                
            }

            if (attrs.zipVisible == "no") {
                scope.zip = false;                   
            }


     } 
}

angular
    .module('app.widgets')
    .directive('ltcgUpdGrid', LtcgUpdGridDirective.instance);
}
```